# I am trying to create a swipe view in Android

Tags: android

Programs run  without error.but when I try to run app it shows unfortunately stopped. My debugger is not working.
code is below.

activity_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

</ViewPager>

 </LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.pathak.swipe;


import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

ViewPager viewPager=null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fragmentManager));
}

}

class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {

    Fragment fragment=null;
    if(i==0)
    {
        fragment=new FragmentA();
    }
    else if(i==1)
    {
        fragment=new FragmentB();
    }
    else if(i==2)
    {
        fragment=new FragmentC();
    }
    else if(i==3)
    {
        fragment=new FragmentD();
    }
    return fragment;
   }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
    return 4;
  }
  }
```

fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:background="#FFCC00"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
 </LinearLayout>
```

FragmentA.java

```
package com.example.pathak.swipe;

 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;

 /**
 * Created by Pathak on 2/3/2016.
 */
  public class FragmentA extends Fragment {    

    @Override

   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    return layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a,container,false);
}
}
```

Similarly three more fragments have been created and their xmls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just replicated the scenario to identify what's wrong more quickly and I noticed in your "activity_main" you need to use the ViewPager from the support library so change the way you declare it in your xml:

```
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

The reason this happens is that in your MainActivity, when you were creating the ViewPager you chose the one from the support library and you can see the import matches that as well. However, you later pass a regular ViewPager from the XML to the one you created and they don't match. It's good that you are using the v4....one!

Now the app runs fine. The way you could identify this yourself is after running the app and after it crashed, you have a look at the log down at

> Android Monitor

You will see a dozen of red lines and if you scroll up to their beginning you sometimes can quite easily identify what your problem is. In this case, I saw it was inflating the ViewPager and then I noticed you don't use the right ViewPager. Good luck and if you are having a hard time look on YouTube or here, there's information about ViewPager, just read carefully.